# Which design pattern can be most suited for building a recursive tree?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-database

I want to choose a design pattern for the below case:
Ancestor Tree: An ancestor tree is a special type of family trees that keeps track of all
known ancestors of a person. The following is the data definition of an ancestor tree.
• An empty ancestor tree is an ancestor tree.

• A non-empty ancestor tree is an ancestor tree that contains
o a String representing the name of a person,
o an int representing the year the person was born,
o an ancestor tree for the person’s father, and
o an ancestor tree for the person’s mother.

Since this looks like a behaviour pattern, will factory pattern be suited for this?

Comment: It looks more like a structural problem, not a behavior one. You probably need Composite.

Answer (score 1):

Your description looks very similar to the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)